# Where should the first I-joist be set parallel to the rim board?

Tags: framing

I have a question about I-Joist layout in framing.  I know that I-Joists are not strong to resist squishing, so that means rim board must be used to help that vertical load, but when you run all your I-Joists the same way, what do you do about the very first joist? No matter what you need rim-board there on the edge of the sill plate, but then do you move 16" over (if doing 16" oc layout) to start the first I-Joist, or do you actually run rim board, sister an I-Joist right next to it, so technically the first I-Joist is centered 2-5/8" from the start of the floor, and then of course the next joist is 16" O.C. from the start of the floor.

I have seen it done with the i-joist sistered against the rim board that is running parallel to the rest of the joists, but not just using rim-board and skipping over the 16" to start the first joist.

Answer (score 1):

...usually if you read the 20-odd pages of documentation that come with your I-joists they will tell you what to do, and a great deal of what not to do. Or ask the person who punches the numbers into the computer to size & select your specific I-joists what their layout program (based on the same manufacturer's data) expects you to do. The number of I-joists you get will be based on that. It's not common to just sell you I-joists at random - they are an engineered system and the specific series and size need to be chosen to fit your building loads - every place I know that sells them provides that service as part of the pre-sales process.

One issue with "just a rim board" and then going (12/16/24 inches, depending on your layout specifics) is that the wall bearing on the rim board is wider (thicker) than the rim joist, and asking the floor-spanning plywood to carry the inside part of the wall load without direct support might lead to problems. Depending on the thickness of the wall, the first I-joist might want to be set at the inner face of the wall, rather than just sistered to the rim board. For a thin wall that might be the same, for a thick wall it might not.

Comment: Interesting point.  Wall plate thicker than the the bearing surface of the rim joist is also the case in traditional framing.  Do you commonly see rim joists doubled up to handle a 2x4 wall above them or tripled up if the wall above is a 2x6 wall?  I think this would only be a problem is the roof load was coming down onto that specific wall and usually the joists are layed out to avoid that.  At the sides of the house where the roof load bears down the joists are likely perpendicular to the rim joist allowing the wall above to have proper bearing.

Comment: Actually I Joists are sold by the 2' section at big box stores. I am given little to no engineering on them besides just the manufacturer contact info. Which, I get it, it's my duty to contact them. But in general the majority of joists are in deflection categories but they all have similiar physics applied to them (where not to bore a hole, what size of hole, what span per layout, etc) I know there are hundreds of TYPES of categories. But in this question, it's just about starting joist layout. And I agree, the idea of *just* rimboard for the start doesn't sound like a good idea for a lot of

Comment: reasons, as you stated the floor itself only fastens to that edge and the 2x6 wall with all the load would not transfer load safely to the sill plate in my opinion. The I Joist sistered with rim board makes me more comfortable. The Rim board allows a nice flat material for exterior OSB to fasten to, while the I-Joist itself is helping carry load vertically with the 2.5" flange + 1.125" rim giving a 3.625" surface area to carry the load which the 3/4" subfloor would then help disperse even more.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to install a sister joist next to the rim joists, as per the manufacturer’s [installation instructions](https://www.weyerhaeuser.com/application/files/5615/6925/1266/TJ-4000.pdf) (it starts on about page 24).

[image]

However, blocking is required at the ends of joists in addition to the rim joists. (See page 20) End nailing is not sufficient to keep the joists from rotating...blocking is required.

Comment: I see on page 20 they mention blocking but that is only for cantilevered applications in the diagram. Do you have any documentation on actually needing blocking (Squash blocks) for the floor joists when it's just a traditional joist bearing on 2x6 plate with the 1-1/8" rim board used to prevent joists from rotating? Plus once the decking is installed, I see no real reason for that blocking unless it is indeed some kind of point load being transferred down...

Comment: @Shumardii You’ll notice blocking panels are required between joists on the left side of the sketch where the joists rests directly on the exterior wall. Blocking is very important to keep the joists from “laying over” like a parallelogram. When the joists are fully loaded they tend to lay over and end nailing through the rim joist into the end of the joists is not strong enough to keep them vertical. Floor decking does nothing to keep the joists vertical.

Comment: I believe that blocking as you talk about is only for their joists in the 18"-24" heights. The common 11-7/8" I Joist does not appear to require blocking between joists there they rest directly on the exterior foundation of crawlspace or basement. What page number are you referring to?

Comment: @Shumardii Ahhh...I think you’re right. If you use a different manufacturer you’ll want to verify their requirements too.

Comment: I am trying to lookup that detail currently, no such luck. I'd think Weyhouser would have it on one of their youtube videos but they never cover it? Another manufacturer said "Use of blocking shall be required whereas no other means of overturning are in use, such as rimboard" or something very similar to that phrase.  I'm thinking that Rimboard indeed counts as the perpendicular blocking on a very traditional framed floor system resting on sill plate on concrete foundations. I'm not 100% sure. I understand point loads need additional blocking.